# How to get values from class list inside a class using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to access class members values inside of list inside of a class. My classes look like this. The `SureViewEvents` class contains the parent level details for an incoming alarm and the `SureViewEventDetails` are the detail values for the alarm. I want to loop through class `SureViewEvents` using LINQ and loop through the details rows if any are populated.

How can I go about doing this?

```
public class SureViewEvents
{
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string DateTimeCreated { get; set; }
    public string GroupTitle { get; set; }
    public string EventTitle { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberId { get; set; }
    public bool Closed { get; set; }

    public List<SureViewEventDetails> Details { get; set; }
}

//EventID|EventRecordID|CreatedDate|EventRecordTypeID|Details|Input1|Input2|EventCode|SubscriberID|EventTitle|SerialNo
public class SureViewEventDetails
{
    public string EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventRecordID { get; set; }
    public string CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string EventRecordTypeID { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Zone { get; set; }
    public string EventCode { get; set; }
    public string SubscriberID { get; set; }
    public string EventTitle { get; set; }
    public int SerialNo { get; set; }
    public bool Handled { get; set; }
}
```

I can retrieve the parent level values using the following, but I am not exactly sure how to access the Details that have been populated using this structure. Any advice is appreciated!

```
var activeEvents = (from sve in m_sureViewEvents 
                    select sve).ToList();

lock (m_driverLock)
{
    foreach (var activeEvent in activeEvents)
    {
        if (activeEvent.Closed == false)
        {
            m_fepConnector.HandleAlarms();
            DownloadZipArchive(activeEvent.EventId);
            CloseSureViewEvent(activeEvent.EventId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select all the details with [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx):

```
foreach (var details in activeEvents.SelectMany(e => e.Details))
{
    // ... Stuff
}
```

This will get all the `SureViewEventDetails` that are in all the `activeEvents`.

Comment: Thanks for you response implementing this now!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your loop for each activeEvent you can simply loop through the details:

```
foreach (var activeEvent in activeEvents)
{
    foreach (var eventDetail in activeEvent.Details)
    {
        // do something with the detail
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't have enough reputation or I would up vote this as well.